# which view to use android

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-view

I am writing a gallery app that has to toggle between the stadard gallery to a 4up view..  The images are loaded from the SDcard and i have a working gallery view that has one row with all the images loading.. works great.  but the specs require that the user be able to toggle from that view to a view that essentially puts all the images into two rows that scroll together.. it would work just like the gallery scrolling left to right and focusing center but instead of one image in center it would be 4 images..  I have been battling trying to figure out the best way to do this, the ammount of images is dynamic as the user will be looking at pictures they took with my custom camera..  any ideas and pointers would be greatly appreciated..